# How are the photos in the “Photos” app organized on a macOS file system?

Tags: macos, mac, photos

I want to access my photos library on my mac. Image files are stored here: `/Users/me/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/originals`

The thing is, they appear to be organized by the first letter of the file. File names look like random hashes.

[image]

Is there a more useful way to traverse images? Like, organized by date rather than this? Is there any useful information distinguishing these folders or it's just random and a picture could be in any one?

Comment: “Is there a more useful way to traverse images?” Via the Finder? Nope. It’s all hashes and folders. But you are meant to browse photos via the “Photos” app; not the Finder.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? I ask because the command line https://rhettbull.github.io/osxphotos/overview.html may be what you need.